# Use js script from one plugin in another plugin

Tags: plugin-development, jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, wp-register-script

I have two plugins that work together (one is an add-on of sorts). In the "main" plugin, I have a js function in  a file located like so:

```
wp-plugins/main-plugin-name/js/main-js.js
```

If my secondary plugin, I have another .js file located like so:

```
wp-plugins/secondary-plugin-name/js/sec-js.js
```

In this second plugin's .js file, I want to use a function located in the first .js file. Basically I want the function to be globally available to both plugins.

I have already registered and enqueued the first .js script using the main plugin, but I can't seem to get the secondary plugin to find the function from the first, and use it.

Here's my current code:

In first plugin:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tps_enqueue_frontend_scripts');
function tps_enqueue_frontend_scripts() {

$plugin_url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );

wp_register_script( 'tps-space-rentals', $plugin_url.'/js/tps-space-rentals.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-datepicker', 'jquery-validate', 'jquery-payment', 'jquery-ui-dialog', 'jquery-ui-tooltip') );
wp_enqueue_script( 'tps-space-rentals' );
}
```

In my other plugin, I have this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'tps_stripe_pay_scripts_enq', 20);
function tps_stripe_pay_scripts_enq() {
$plugin_url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );

wp_register_script( 'tps-stripe-payments', $plugin_url.'js/tps-stripe-payments.js', array('jquery', 'tps-space-rentals'), '', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'tps-stripe-payments' );       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that determines whether a function is available in another script is if it has been loaded before the other script attempts to use it. This is simply a matter of putting the `<script></script>` tag for the script with the function you need to use before the tag of the script that needs to use it*.

The most reliable way to guarantee that the script you depend on has loaded before the script that needs it is to use the dependencies argument of `wp_enqueue_script()`:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'dependency', '/path/to/dependency.js' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'script', '/path/to/script.js', array( 'dependency' ) );
```

The 3rd argument is an array of handles (the first argument) for scripts that the script depends on. This ensures that `'dependency'` will be loaded whenever `'script'` is enqueued, and before it.

*Unless you're doing something unusual like loading scripts asynchronously, which WordPress doesn't support with `wp_enqueue_script()` out of the box.

Comment: Thank you. As far as I know I'm not doing anything asynchronously. I've added more code to my question with the enqueue script for both plugins. I'm still not able to call a function from the first plugin from the second plugin for some reason.

Comment: Sorry, I just read your answer again. Should I be using wp_enqueue_script INSTEAD of wp_register_script for this?

Comment: Either works. Depends on context. If you never need to load the dependency alone, just register it and it will get loaded whenever the dependent script is enqueued.