# How to avoid conflict if a plugin already have included open library?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I am trying to use the swiper the library.
https://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/

But the Elementor plugin is already added that :
https://github.com/elementor/elementor/tree/master/assets/lib/swiper

Now it seems to have a conflict on CSS and javascript levels, any way to get over this? or any way to use the same library from the plugin

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/285651/use-js-script-from-one-plugin-in-another-plugin

Comment: There's no secret trick that will help you here. If a popular plugin or theme is loading the same library, then check its source code for the handle it uses for those scripts and styles. Then you can check if that plugin is active and enqueue their version, rather than your own.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yeah, I understood. I got the answer from another question that you have answered but couldn't mark it as duplicate as it was not marked as an accepted answer there. Thanks